# DWR and Spring together on Google App Engine

Tags: java, spring, swing, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

I am trying to put DWR and Spring together on Google App Engine (GAE).
(follow the instructions : http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/server/integration/spring.html#springMVC),

### Error:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:javax.swing.event.EventListenerList is a restricted class`

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Looks like a classpath issue.  I'd start by ensuring all required JARs are there and are the right version needed.  Also, make sure you don't have duplicate JARs of different verisons.

Comment: The project is running on apache-tomcat now, but I want to migrate a project to GAE. I know that the Java swing libraries are not allowed on GAE, can you propose an equivalent class?Thanks in advance

Comment: Java Swing is a GUI library for stand alone apps.  GAE is a web-based technology.  I think you are mixing up technologies.